# mypy: how to define method typing bound to class variable

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have abstract class which defines a set of methods and assumes that all children have class var set.

To get the idea, that's what I tried.

```py
import abc
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class Parent(abc.ABC):
    validator_cls: Type[T]

    def process_data(self, data: dict[str, Any]) -> T:
        entry = validator_cls(**data)
        # do something
        return entry

class ChildOne(Parent):
    validator_cls = SomeValidator
    
    def process_data(self, data):
        entry = self.validator_cls(**data)  # entry is not recognized as `SomeValidator`
        return entry
```

Unfortunately, while all children classes have validator class attached, mypy do not inherit that class in childrens' calls (e.g. it shows 'Any' for entry var).

What should I do to make mypy understand the type of the entry?

Comment: Please write code that compiles! Where are the imports for `abc` and `Any`? Your code should only produce the mypy warnings that are pertinent to your question, not lots of others.

Comment: [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#user-defined-generic-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `TypeVar` is a callable, not subscriptable.

```
T = TypeVar("T")
```

Second, it sounds like you wants a [`Generic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) class. The `T` variable isn't in scope, and the easiest way to introduce it is with `Generic` at the class level.

```
class Parent(Generic[T], abc.ABC):
  ...
```

Now your child specifies its type in subscripts.

```
class ChildOne(Parent[SomeValidator]):
  validator_cls = SomeValidator
  ...
```

Finally, since `validator_cls` is a type, we can't construct it with keyword arguments of type `dict[str, Any]` (after all, the base type `object` takes no arguments). It seems to me that you want mypy to simply accept that `data` is probably correct and *not* typecheck that. If so, cast to `Any`.

```
entry = cast(Any, self.validator_cls)(**data)
```

[`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) is in the `typing` module, alongside `Generic`, `Any`, and all of the other typing techniques.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding TypeVar callable - fixed in the question.